# Sum csv-entries in a field in excel without a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let's say I have in my Excel sheet in field `A1` the content

```
1, 2,3,4,5, 10
```

then I want to have a classic excel formula combination to sum the entries up, e.g., I want to type in `A2` a forumla

```
= COMBINATION_OF_WEIRD_EXCEL_FUNCTIONS(A1)
```

which should basically be a Excel SUM()-functionality for a field with csv-values.

**This needs to be achivied without a macro**. I already have a macro based solution to this, and this is bad for many reasons, for example if you are using Excel online in OneDrive, macros don't work...